# PDF file name appears different than actual file name in Chrome viewer

Tags: html, google-chrome, pdf

1. I have a PDF file with name X on my local machine
2. I rename X to Y locally
3. I push the PDF file to the server where my personal website is
   hosted
4. I navigate to the PDF file on my website

The URL shows the filename Y, and when you save (download) the file, it is defaulted to name Y, but inside Chrome, the PDF is displayed (in a built in PDF viewer?), and the title is X.

Why is this happening? I opened the webpage in incognito mode and on a friend's computer and it still shows filename X inside Chrome. I am using the latest version of Chrome as of now.

EDIT: I tried again by opening the HTML file locally, and navigating to the PDF file, and it still has the same problem...

Comment: Maybe server cache or load-balancing? Do you use Cloudflare or something similar?

Comment: I just tried opening the html file through localhost and navigated to the PDF, it still displays a different file name...

Answer (score 1):

Resolved. I found that, in the PDF's metadata, the Title was the same as the old filename for the PDFs that were affected.